# How to step into standard library while debugging?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging

I was curious to see how `pickle` works and wanted to learn with debugging.

I have already searched for this question and disabled `justMyCode`, below is my `launch.json` file:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false,
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is a simple program I tried to debug, I have put breakpoint on line 4, hoping to get inside `dumps` call, even I put break point in standard library `_dumps` method as well. It is not working, not allowing me to step into that function.

```py
import pickle

obj = {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 5, 6]}
serialized_obj = pickle.dumps(obj)

print(serialized_obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Debug actions

Once a debug session starts, the **Debug toolbar** will appear on the top of the editor.

[image]

| Action | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| Continue / Pause `F5` | **Continue**: Resume normal program/script execution (up to the next breakpoint). **Pause**: Inspect code executing at the current line and debug line-by-line. |
| Step Over `F10` | Execute the next method as a single command without inspecting or following its component steps. |
| Step Into `F11` | Enter the next method to follow its execution line-by-line. |
| Step Out `Shift+F11` | When inside a method or subroutine, return to the earlier execution context by completing remaining lines of the current method as though it were a single command. |
| Restart `Ctrl+Shift+F5` | Terminate the current program execution and start debugging again using the current run configuration. |
| Stop `Shift+F5` | Terminate the current program execution. |

*https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_debug-actions*

[image]

Comment: yeah, I am pressing that button but it's not stepping into `pickle.dumps` is it working for you?

Comment: Try switching interpreters.

Comment: I am using `python-venv` Which environment are you using? `anaconda`, `poetry`?

Comment: Either way, I use a virtual environment..

Comment: I have also a virtual environment but it's not working for me.